# Trying to run pyspark code on docker image of aws_glue on mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, jupyter-lab, aws-glue-spark

The following error I get.

The code failed because of a fatal error. Some things to try: a) Make sure Spark has enough available resources for Jupyter to create a Spark context. b) Contact your Jupyter administrator to make sure the Spark magics library is configured correctly.   c) Restart the kernel.

How can i make sure that i have enough resources?
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You can add some runtime [flags](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) to `docker run`  Note: you may need to allocate more resources to the engine in Docker Desktop Settings